# python conditional constructor for giving object or None

Tags: python

I receive UDP packets with GPS data, and construct Position objects with them.
Sometimes, GPS loss satellite signal, but still send UDP packets with no valuable data. I would like the Position constructor gives me a 'None' object in this failure cases. So, I could check if process the Position or not. Something like that:

```
frameGPS = giveMeTheFrame()
position1 = Position(frameGPS)
if (position1 is None): don't process position1
else: process position1
```

Is this a right way to do it?
If so, how could I implement this **init**?

Comment: You cannot return anything from `__init__`. Your best bet is to raise an Exception in `__init__` which should be caught and handled in your main code.

Comment: What would `giveMeTheFrame()` return to indicate to you that you have lost satellite signal?

Comment: If the frame is OK, the frame will have N or S (North or South) and E or W (East or West) in a way I check with regex

Comment: So, in the event that it is useless data, it would return an empty string? or None?

Comment: In the event of useless data I receive lots of zeroes (garbage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As coldspeed said, you can't return from `__init__`. What you *can* do is initialize the object to an "empty" state. Make your `Position` object do something like this.

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        if some_condition:
            self.okay = True
            # Success; load the frame data into Position ...
        else:
            self.okay = False
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.okay
```

Then you can use it in an if-statement like you wanted to.

```
frameGPS = giveMeTheFrame()
position1 = Position(frameGPS)
if position1:
    # Success; do some work ...
else:
    # Failure; GPS lost signal ...
```

Note that in Python 2.x, the relevant method is called [`__nonzero__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__), not [`__bool__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__). So, use `__nonzero__()` if you are in Python 2.x, use `__bool__()` if you are in Python 3.x

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways you can approach this. The answer just posted by implementing `__bool__` is a very good option too!

To provide another approach as well:

Per your comment on what is considered garbage data, and what is considered valid data. Let us say you receive valid characters as coordinates. To keep it simple:

`N`, `S`, `E`, `W`

One way, is you can have your class *raise* if it is given invalid data to properly instantiate an instance of that class:

```
def Position:
    def __init__(self, position):
        if position.upper() not in {'N', 'S', 'E', 'W'}:
            raise InvalidPositionData('Received unexpected data {}'.format(position))
        self.position = position
```

In your code, you can simply wrap to catch that exception:

```
frameGPS = giveMeTheFrame()
try:
    position1 = Position(frameGPS)
except InvalidPositionData as exc:
    # do things with your exception here
    log.error('something bad happened')
# continue with logic here
```

Comment: I would urge caution at the use of exceptions for something like this. Exceptions in Python, as they are in many languages, are reserved for *exceptional* circumstances, not correct program behavior.

Comment: But in defining the *contract* for something, using exception handling allows you to set the boundaries on what you define as exceptional in this case.

Comment: If your program takes some series of particular data, and you want to make sure that this data is held to the contract, you want to make sure that you explain this clearly by "raising" to the caller why their call did not work. So, if invalid input is provided, it is perfectly fine to raise that exception accordingly in the form of some custom `InvalidData` exception.